# Controlling Windows Screen Orientation in C++/Qt/Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, orientation, nvidia

I am looking for a solution to control the screen orientation from within my application.
1. Qt program compiled with visual C++ 2013 (express)
2. Nvidia (if this matters)

I do not just want to control the orientation of the window because this will fail to change the orientation of any onscreen keyboard applications running.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using *ChangeDisplaySettings* from the windows API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411%28VS.85%29.aspx

example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

DEVMODE mode;
//first get setting for "current" screen
EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &mode);

if (mode.dmFields | DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION)
{
    mode.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180;
    LONG r;
    r = ChangeDisplaySettings(&mode, 0);
    std::cout << "result: " << r;
}
```

Look here for info on DEVMODE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using pyautogui.hotkey

```
from pyautogui import hotkey
hotkey('ctrl','Alt','down')
```